# Play JSON serialize/deserialize

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm trying to go create some formats for this:

```
  case class Work[T](todo: Seq[T], failed: Seq[T], success: Seq[T])

  object Work {
    implicit def format[T](implicit r: Reads[T], w: Writes[T]): Format[Work[T]] = Json.format[Work[T]]
  }

  object InternalMessage {
    implicit def format[D, R](implicit
                              rD: Reads[D],
                              wD: Writes[D],
                              rR: Reads[R],
                              wR: Writes[R]
                             ): Format[InternalMessage[D, R]] = Json.format[InternalMessage[D, R]]

  }

  case class InternalMessage[D, R](
                                    download: List[Work[D]],
                                    refine: List[Work[R]],
                                    numberOfTries: Int
                                  )
```

This doesn't work and I don't understand why. The error is

```
[error] /home/oleber/develop/data-platform/modules/importerTemplate/src/main/scala/template/TemplateModel.scala:46: No apply function found matching unapply parameters
[error]     implicit def format[T](implicit r: Reads[T], w: Writes[T]): Format[Work[T]] = Json.format[Work[T]]
[error]                                                                                              ^
[error] /home/oleber/develop/data-platform/modules/importerTemplate/src/main/scala/template/TemplateModel.scala:55: No apply function found matching unapply parameters
[error]                              ): Format[InternalMessage[D, R]] = Json.format[InternalMessage[D, R]]
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your code seems to compiles fine. Have you added other `apply` or `unapply` methods in `Work` object?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet, what Scala/Play versions do you use? I can cofirm that I get the same error for the `Work[T]` class on Scala 2.11.11 with `play-json` version `2.5.15` explicitly referenced from build.sbt (i.e. no other explicit Play dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU you can't generate JSON `Format` for such data types using Play 2.5 macros. What is limiting you is that you use `Seq[T]` i.e. you want JSON serialization for a generic class that has fields that use some complex type built from that generic type rather than just raw generic `T`. Relevant code seems to be in the [`JsMacroImpl` lines 135-141](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsMacroImpl.scala#L135-L141). In those lines inside `paramsMatch` inner method of `maybeApply` calculation the macro checks if there are an `apply` and `unapply` methods with matching (complement) signatures:

```
val maybeApply = applies.collectFirst {
  case (apply: MethodSymbol) if hasVarArgs && {
    // Option[List[c.universe.Type]]
    val someApplyTypes = apply.paramLists.headOption.map(_.map(_.asTerm.typeSignature))
    val someInitApply = someApplyTypes.map(_.init)
    val someApplyLast = someApplyTypes.map(_.last)
    val someInitUnapply = unapplyReturnTypes.map(_.init)
    val someUnapplyLast = unapplyReturnTypes.map(_.last)
    val initsMatch = someInitApply == someInitUnapply
    val lastMatch = (for {
      lastApply <- someApplyLast
      lastUnapply <- someUnapplyLast
    } yield lastApply <:< lastUnapply).getOrElse(false)
    initsMatch && lastMatch
  } => apply

  case (apply: MethodSymbol) if {
    val applyParams = apply.paramLists.headOption.
      toList.flatten.map(_.typeSignature)
    val unapplyParams = unapplyReturnTypes.toList.flatten

    def paramsMatch = (applyParams, unapplyParams).zipped.forall {
      case (TypeRef(NoPrefix, applyParam, _),
        TypeRef(NoPrefix, unapplyParam, _)) => // for generic parameter
        applyParam.fullName == unapplyParam.fullName

      case (applyParam, unapplyParam) => applyParam =:= unapplyParam
    }

    (applyParams.size == unapplyParams.size && paramsMatch)
  } => apply
}
```

As you can see in the relevant (non-`hasVarArgs` branch), this code only handles two cases: when the types in `apply` and `unapply` match exactly or when the same raw generic type is used. Your case of `Seq[T]` (as well as other complex generic types) is not handled here and the error you get is generated just a few lines down when `maybeApply` is empty:

```
val (tparams, params) = maybeApply match {
  case Some(apply) => {
    apply.typeParams -> apply.paramLists.head
    // assume there is a single parameter group
  }

  case None => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "No apply function found matching unapply parameters")
}
```

In Play-JSON 2.6 this code was significantly re-worked and now it seems to support your case as well (see [`conforms` inner method](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/JsMacroImpl.scala#L236-L284)).

If upgrading to (not released yet) Play-JSON 2.6 is not acceptable, you can create `Formats` object(s) yourself using [JSON Reads/Writes/Format Combinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) doc. Something like this should work for you:

```
  implicit def format[T](implicit r: Reads[T], w: Writes[T]): Format[Work[T]] = {
    val workReads = (
      (JsPath \ "todo").read[Seq[T]] and
        (JsPath \ "failed").read[Seq[T]] and
        (JsPath \ "success").read[Seq[T]]
      ) (Work.apply[T] _)

    val workWrites = (
      (JsPath \ "todo").write[Seq[T]] and
        (JsPath \ "failed").write[Seq[T]] and
        (JsPath \ "success").write[Seq[T]]
      ) (unlift(Work.unapply[T]))

    new Format[Work[T]] {
      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Work[T]] = workReads.reads(json)

      override def writes(o: Work[T]): JsValue = workWrites.writes(o)
    }
  }
```